# Serializing and deserializing group elements in Charm-Crypto

Tags: python, cryptography, charm-crypto

I need help to convert the list representation (string) of elliptic curve pairing group element back to an object.

Explanation:
I am using charm crypto v0.43 to use CPABE scheme in my web application. I need to store the pairing element that is generated into my database. When I did that, it is storing it as list. I need to map it back to pairing group element object.

Convert:

```
[771281202364725359015275543519860265278248937600027018972741977722880288402810467924555583431036045929994018001453439703799448692568829067937466068366897, 5928426678871551838449004494119368314093842432141364739971117261348155912543962117516776973405646414105108743246860323245910977796691638669773215755592297]
```

to

```
<pairing.Element object at 0x7f1a1e840300>`
```

Code:

```
group = PairingGroup('SS512')
alpha = group.random(ZR)
g= group.random(G1)
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you have made an attempted at writing code to meet your requirement, please post the code and explain the problem you are having with it.

Comment: I have tried pickling it. Converting it to json and so. But no use.

Comment: @Blackwood
I a bit confused about StackOverflow now. But i have seen many simple questions asked in this site and answered well. I did tried things like pickling, converting to json etc.

Comment: This is a understandable question *now* (but may need a little more editing). There were too few details to provide a meaningful answer before your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem. Here is what i did.You can use groups serialize function.

```
g = group.random(G1) # generates a random group element in that pairing group
```

You can serialize `g` using groups serialize function:

```
str = group.serialize(g)
```

You can deserialize it using

```
obj = group.deserialize(str)
```

Hope it might help somebody facing the same issue.